# Binary message queue using Redis

Tags: redis, message-queue

I wonder if it is feasible to use Redis for exchanging binary messages between node?

For example node1 will send with `RPUSH`
and consuming node2 could use `LPOP` to get a value from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very possible - Redis' values are 101% binary-safe so you can dump anything into it. Specifically, using Redis Lists for messaging is a common pattern, although calling [`BLPOP`](http://redis.io/commands/blpop) is preferable for getting extra oompf of async-ness.